# how multi-platform is Qt

Tags: ios, qt, app-store, multiplatform

I am planning to make a simple program, and consider to make it in Qt. I read that programs made in Qt could be run in different operating systems. Does it mean that when I create a desktop application for Windows, it would be executable in a smartphone? I just doesn't fit in my mind. For example, I don't have iOS experience, but as far as I know you need to have a Mac computer or at least to make specific configuration to Windows computer in order to develop applications. Now, if I use Qt in standard Windows(no configs.), would that program really run on iOS and could it be transferred to Appstore just with the payment without any modifications? I have always worked just in Windows, and mainly in Java. The "multiplatform" concept made me consider to start development in Qt, but I am not sure because I don't understand it well. I would appreciate if you could clarify.

Comment: why not build the examples from the Qt website and see how it goes?

Comment: Your question are very broad. The purpose of stackoverflow is to solve specific programming problems.

Comment: Well, if I start development in Java, my program would end max. in a month; if I consider Qt, it would take much longer. Before starting I want to make sure that it will be indeed simple Qt headers and pure C++ and it would work as intended. Turning into non-familiar environment would take additional time. I need to make sure it is worth that effort. If at the end, what I will get would be that Windows program will work fine just on Linux,  and would require much effort for adaptation to other systems,  I would go with Java.

Comment: All I need to know is that after I finish development on Windows with all the tutorials and etc. , at the end, which platforms would run that .exe file and how complicated is to transfer that .exe into mobile platforms

Comment: @UserRR , you won't be *running the .exe on platforms other than windows*. The C++ code you write in Qt, can be compiled on all platforms supported by Qt. Qt's tagline is "write once compile everywhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that programs made in Qt could be run in different operating systems

No. You have to **re-compile** your application on each target system.

Java is different. Java code is compiled into a special binary that is run by Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Because JVM is multi-platform you can usually run a java application in any platform you have JVM available.

When you compile a Qt application which is most likely written in C++, it's linked to OS libraries and as a result that application will only run on that OS.

Now, Qt is a multi-platform SDK, the code you write using Qt can be compiled for all the platforms that [Qt supports](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html) and results will be same or *similar*. I say similar because, for example Qt tries to emulate native widgets of the operation system. You will have to test and maybe tweak your application according to target OS. Mobile user interfaces are very different than desktop, so you may have to re-implement GUI of your application separately for mobile.

Comment: No, no. Qt does not emulate anything, QT ships with it's own renderer if thats what you mean. While it might not look perfectly like the OS it is being run on it will however look the same on all supported OSs. So you generally have to tweak and test only once, and you can do it on your system of choice because the results should be the same. Last but not least you can compile for almost any platform on Linux and Windows as a base, you just need to set the appropriate compilers up.

Comment: "QT ships with it's own renderer if thats what you mean", that is what I was trying to say indeed.

Comment: The answer is not entirely correct, though for the part it was meant to be it is. Just pointing out to interested readers, that there are ways to develop trully multiplaform. I.e.  if you make your application in PyQt, *it will run across all the platforms with the same code base* as far as the proper python environment is set and all dependencies satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The base code will be the same on all platforms, but you will need xcode and a Mac to build your applications to iOS platform.

Comment: what is the difference between the base code and the latter?

Comment: i.e. If there is an exclusive functionality of iOS, not covered by the Qt framework, you would have to create a 'iOS only' case in the code. Try running the examples to see how Qt handles multi-platforming.

Comment: Thank you. Would I need to add IOS only code in Mac? Does mac provide tools to combine these codes?

Comment: Depends on what you're coding. You should research about the Qt framework capabilites, what kind of specific-platform features it covers. But you will need a mac with x code to deploy your code to an iPhone(i.e.) anyway.